# Why am I getting a TypeError the second time I run a class method?

Tags: python, function, class, methods

New to Python and programming in general.  Currently learning about classes and objects and really struggling.  In this particular example, I have an Animal parent class and a EggLayers child class.  The EggLayers class has a method to calculate a particular instance's egg production for the week and then append the value to a list. I have another method that calculates the chicken's lifetime production.  The idea being, each week's totals go into a list from running the first method and then the second method sums the list to return a lifetime total for the instance. Both run fine the first time around, however, when I try to run the first method a second time I get a TypeError ('int' object is not callable).

I've tried int() in various places in the code. Also don't think I'm overriding the int() function anywhere. Apparently these are the two most common reasons for this error. Wouldn't think it would run the first time if I had either of the above issues.

```
class EggLayers(Animal):
    """A class for egg laying animals"""
    type = "chicken"

    def __init__(self, name, age, color, tag):
        super().__init__(name, age, color, tag)

    def eggs_week(self):    # to calculate eggs/week and then append to list
        self.eggs_list = []
        self.eggs_day = int(input("Eggs today?  "))
        self.eggs_day = self.eggs_day
        self.eggs_week = self.eggs_day * 7
        self.eggs_list.append(self.eggs_week)
        print(f"{self.name} laid {self.eggs_week} this week")
        return self.eggs_week

    def eggs_lifetime(self):  # to sum the values in the list above
        self.eggs_lifetime = sum(self.eggs_list)
        print(f"Liftetime production for {self.name} is {self.eggs_lifetime}")
        return self.eggs_lifetime

chicken1 = EggLayers('chicken1', 3, 'white', '002')

chicken1.eggs_week()
chicken1.eggs_lifetime()
chicken1.eggs_week() # Only throws an error the second time
```

Comment: The first time you call `EggLayers.eggs_week`, you create an *instance* attribute that shadows the class attribute. Most of your instance attributes look like they should simply be local variables that don't need to survive a given call to the method.

Comment: (The same thing should happen the second time you call `chicken1.eggs_lifetime()` for the same reason.)

Comment: Please, in the future when you ask a question, if you are getting an error, **always post the full error message including the stack trace**. The python runtime goes to great lengths to provide that *precisely because* it helps in debugging.

Comment: Taking a step back, you keep creating instance variables where you probably shouldn't be. This is what caused your bug. In general, all instance variables should be defineid in `__init__`. Most of the instance variables you are creating in the other methods should probably just be regular local variables

Comment: Okay so, within my functions I should use random variables so as not to continually update the instance variables. Say I wanted the function to update the instance variable though... Would I assign just that variable to the instance variable at the end of the function?

Comment: @RyanR.McKnight *local* variables. yes. And if a method mutates an instance variable, that's fine. But a good rule of thumb is that *new instance variables should only be created in `__init__`*.

Answer (score 3):

It's because in your `eggs_week` function, you have

```
        self.eggs_week = self.eggs_day * 7
```

After that, `chicken1.eggs_week` is no longer a function.  It's an integer.

You don't really need to include a prefix on your function names, since it's already an eggs-related class.  Also, most of the values you compute do not need to be saved as state in the object, so they do not need `self.`.

More like this:

```
class EggLayers(Animal):
    """A class for egg laying animals"""
    type = "chicken"

    def __init__(self, name, age, color, tag):
        super().__init__(name, age, color, tag)
        self.eggs_list = []

    def per_week(self):    # to calculate eggs/week and then append to list
        eggs_day = int(input("Eggs today?  "))
        eggs_week = eggs_day * 7
        self.eggs_list.append(eggs_week)
        print(f"{self.name} laid {eggs_week} this week")
        return eggs_week

    def lifetime(self):  # to sum the values in the list above
        eggs_lifetime = sum(self.eggs_list)
        print(f"Liftetime production for {self.name} is {eggs_lifetime}")
        return eggs_lifetime
```

Personally, I think it is bad practice to do I/O in a class method like this.  The class should hold functionality directly related to the object.  It should not care where the information comes from.  For example, right now, you couldn't easily use this to read the data from a file or a database.

I would have a loop outside the class asking for the input, then have a class method that allows me to pass that information in, like `add_week`.  However, I haven't made that change here.

Comment: I would emphasize that you stopped assigning to instance attributes and instead used local variables in the method

Comment: Ahhh, so to be clear, because my function name and variable name are the same, one replaces the other. Makes total sense. I had been thinking the, () after the function name would distinguish it from a variable of the same name. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Nope, all names are the same.  An object only has one namespace.  Same thing happens at the global level.  Saying `open = 7` will remove the normal file `open` function from your use.

Comment: @RyanR.McKnight `()` is essentially like an operator. It *acts* upon the result of the expression, so  `self.whatever` is an expression, which results in an object. Then, `()` tries to *call that object*. But in this case, `self.whaeter` is an `int`, but `int` objects are not callable. You can get the same error by doing `f = 42` then `print(f())`